# How would I create a daily report of changes made to a google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, report

I have a sheet that gets used for inputting tracking information of parts being shipped out. Each part is a single line but can have multiple tracking numbers. Is there a way to create a daily readout/report of what lines have had tracking information put into them, as well as copying that whole line onto a report?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.